# How to store human readable IP in struct in_addr?

Tags: c, networking, ip-address, gethostbyaddr

Say if you have the following IP address:

```
192.168.0.255
```

How can I store that human readable IP address into a `struct in_addr`? I'm brand new to network programming in C at this low level, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for and read about `inet_pton`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
struct in_addr p;
inet_aton("192.168.0.255", &p.s_addr);
```